# When I am browsing a file using intents it's not going to File Manager?

Tags: android, android-intent, file-manager

When i click on the Browse button i have added below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);    
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_FILE_REQUESTCODE);
```

It shows FileManager in some devices like Redmi,Asus,Micromax.But it is not showing in Samsung phones,it's not going to file manager

How to get FileManager in Samsung phones to select a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this is working for me

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(intent , CHOOSE_FILE_REQUESTCODE);
```

for Samsung Devices

```
String manufactures = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
    if(manufactures.equalsIgnoreCase("samsung")){
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA");              
        intent.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_FILE_REQUESTCODE); 
    }
```

Comment: It's not showing FileManager,it is showing some apps like Choose music track,Drive,Contacts,Dropbox,Gallery,Photos.But it not showing FileManger to select file(In Samsung Galaxy,Samsung Note).

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```

as

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.GET_CONTENT);
```

**EDIT**

@Hanuman i think that single solution that fits all models doesn't exist, all intents with "actions" have to be processed by choosers. If you use >= 4.4 devices, I recommend 
[Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html)